# Education Assignments returns Access Denied

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I am having issues accessing Education Assignment using Microsoft Grap returning "Access Denied", even though we have all the required permissions.

I noticed that under [Application Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), it requires one of these permissions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq81L.jpg)

But under API Permission >  Application Permission, we actually have `EduAssignments.ReadBasic.All`, `EduAssignments.ReadWriteBasic.All`, `EduAssignments.Read.All`, and `EduAssignments.ReadWrite.All`:

[image: permission displayed in the actual permissions tab]

I am not sure whether this is an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid these particular Application scopes are still in limited public preview. The documentation unfortunately fails to properly explain how these work.

I've asked for the documentation to be updated to explain this limitation as well as the process for gaining access to the preview.